# Categories filtering in new post

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, filters

I have a website with post types that have subtitles for movies.  That files are on a specific custom post type using http://www.wpdownloadmanager.com/ pro.  Because all custom type posts are movies we have a lot of categories.  744 for now.  We have Letter Cattegory including Movie or Series Name and sub categories with Season.

I am wondering if there is an easy way to select categories and sub categories in Backend when a users creates an new post so there is no need to look on a 744 categories to find the movie.

Maybe somekind of filtering or by selecting a main category and filtering child categories ( Movi name ) and after that by filtering sub child categories (Seasons).

Otherwise user needs to seach on 744 Categories to check them.

Comment: Multiple specialized taxonomies, perhaps?